# Control used for Microsoft Word Option Window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word

I'm trying to design an option screen that is similar to the one in Word 2010.

[image]

What is the control used for the menu that is to the left side of the Option Screen? (Windows Forms). If there isn't a control available in windows forms that exactly replicates the menu bar, what would be the most recommended approach of designing the option screen?

Also, I'd like to save the settings onto a file so that the saved settings are automatically loaded by the application the next time it is launched. What is the most common way of handling this? (I thought XML but not sure if that is appropriate for saving settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a control like the dialog shown, but the `Tab Control` is probably the closest:

[image]

You can add more tabs and place controls inside of each tab. This is probably the best option if you don't want to use external libraries.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is getting a 3rd party library that does controls. [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) has a really good one and you can get something very close to what Word does with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can go for third party controls that should be the first choice because not only this you would get many more good looking controls. But they cost $$$ and just for one control you might not want to buy them. So try to create a similar look and feel using existing .Net controls...

Drop a ToolStrip on your form, change its Dock from Top to Left and set the GripStyle to Hidden. Add Buttons to it and set the button's DisplayStyle to Text. You get quite similar looks... you can add separators as well and you can have toggle buttons as well by setting the Checked property of groupled buttons and so on

You might not get the exact look and feel but it might be close and you might decide against buying the third party controls...You can check out the RenderMode of the ToolStrip to see what style you prefer...